# Angular: prevent user from printing in text input

Tags: angular

I have a text input, which can be changed from another control, and use can click on it, but I want to prevent a user from enter value to this input. I don't want to use `disabled` attribute, because of click on this input fire another event and I want the user to be able to select and copy the value inside. How can I prevent any typing in this input?

Comment: Maybe the readonly attribute could be helpful?

Comment: @GeckoIT oh. shame on me, I totally forgot about this attribute... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML readonly attribute. It is a Boolean attribute that is used to specify that the text written in input or text area Element is read-only. It means that a user can not modify or changes a content already present in a particular Element (However, a user can tab to it, highlight it, and copy the text from it).

```js
function myFun(){
  var a=document.getElementById("txt2").value;
  document.getElementById("txt1").value=a;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <label>Read only text box</label>
  Textbox 1: <input readonly type='text' id="txt1" placeholder="read only text box">

  <label>Enter your name</label>
  Textbox 2: <input type='text' id="txt2" onkeyup="myFun()">
</pre>
```

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the input field as a readonly input and add a click function to trigger the other function.

```
<input type = "text" matInput id="first_name" formControlName="first_name" readonly (click) = "onChange()">
```

And In the onChange() method,

```
onChange() {
   console.log('this is the event');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the whole case but you can use a form-validation with a formGroup which prevent to change the value, but it is still editable.

example.html:

```
<div *ngIf="!name; else forminfo">
  <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)">
    <div class="form-container">
      <div class="row columns">
        <h1>My Reactive Form</h1>
        <label>Name
          <input type="text" formControlName="name">
        </label>
        <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['name'].valid && rForm.controls['name'].touched">{{ titleAlert }}</div>

        <label>Description
          <textarea  formControlName="description"></textarea>
        </label>
        <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['description'].valid && rForm.controls['description'].touched">You must specify a description that's between 30 and 500 characters.</div>

        <label for="validate">Minimum of 3 Characters</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="validate" formControlName="validate" value="1"> On

        <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Submit Form" [disabled]="!rForm.valid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<ng-template #forminfo>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="row columns">
      <h1>{{ name }}</h1>

      <p>{{ description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

---

example.ts

```
import { AfterViewChecked, Component, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  rForm: FormGroup;
  post: any;                     // A property for our submitted form
  description: string = '';
  name: string = '';
  validate: boolean = false;
  titleAlert: string = 'This field is required';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.rForm = fb.group({
      'name' : [null, Validators.required],
      'description' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(30), Validators.maxLength(500)])],
      'validate' : ''
    });

  }
  addPost(post) {
    this.description = post.description;
    this.name = post.name;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.rForm.get('validate').valueChanges.subscribe(

      (validate) => {
        console.log('check validate...');

        if (validate === true) {
          this.rForm.get('name').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
          this.titleAlert = 'You need to specify at least 3 characters';
        } else {
          this.rForm.get('name').setValidators(Validators.required);
        }
        this.rForm.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();

      });
  }
}
```